# Losing focus on SwingX JCOMBO BOX

Tags: java, swingx

I want to achieve AutoSuggest ComboBox 2 problems I am facing 
1st getting an array of id and name both want the name only.
[Array i am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmoJd.png)
2nd losing focus on typing the text.

Please help

database Query

```
public SentenceList getAutoProductList() {
    return new StaticSentence(s, "SELECT "
            + "P.ID, "
            + "P.REFERENCE, "
            + "P.CODE, "
            + "P.CODETYPE, "
            + "P.NAME, "
            + "P.PRICEBUY, "
            + "P.PRICESELL, "
            + "P.CATEGORY, "
            + "P.TAXCAT, "
            + "P.ATTRIBUTESET_ID, "
            + "P.STOCKCOST, "
            + "P.STOCKVOLUME, "
            + "P.IMAGE, "
            + "P.ISCOM, "
            + "P.ISSCALE, "
            + "P.ISKITCHEN, "
            + "P.PRINTKB, "
            + "P.SENDSTATUS, "
            + "P.ISSERVICE, "
            + "P.ATTRIBUTES, "
            + "P.DISPLAY, "
            + "P.ISVPRICE, "
            + "P.ISVERPATRIB, "
            + "P.TEXTTIP, "
            + "P.WARRANTY, "
            + "P.STOCKUNITS "
            + "FROM PRODUCTS P "
            + "ORDER BY NAME", null, ProductInfoExt.getSerializerRead());
}
```

Auto Complete JcomboBox Code

```
SentenceList sentProductNames = dlSales.getAutoProductList();
    m_JComboProductName.setEditable(true);
    ComboBoxValModel m_jProductNameModel = new ComboBoxValModel();
    editor = (JTextComponent) m_JComboProductName.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

    List productList = null;
    try {
        productList = sentProductNames.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    productList.add(0, null);
    m_jProductNameModel = new ComboBoxValModel(productList);

    m_JComboProductName.setModel(m_jProductNameModel);
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(m_JComboProductName);
    System.out.println("product List "+ productList);
    if(m_JComboProductName.getItemCount()>0){
        m_JComboProductName.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
```